# Range Find Date Column

Tags: excel, vba

The below procedure sometimes gives wrong output. 
Can someone modify it such that when date to be searched is not available then
it should increment the date by 1 and search again until it finds the available date.

Example : If i search for "1/1/2012" and if its not available then it should increment the
date to "2/1/2012" and process the search until it finds the match value and return range address if found.

Note : The range format "M/d/yyyy"

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find("1/1/2012")

Debug.Print rng.Address
'output $A$3288
'"1/1/2012" is not available.
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: try to add additional parameters of `.Find` method: `Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find("1/1/2012", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`

Comment: so, I copy into answer that you could match as solved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy from comment to match the question as solved...

...try to add additional parameters of `.Find` method:

```
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find("1/1/2012", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: Dude, you've literally saved my evening. Stupid excel!! Thanks dude! Best of luck to you!!!